# Can we add our own banner in .net Set up project?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, installation, setup-deployment

I am using **.net set up project** and I have added my own banner image to it.

My image has logo on left side and the "Welcome to ...." text is overlapping the logo on image. Can we create only banner part?

Or at least change the alignment of the welcome text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the welcome banner in the welcome UI dialog.  right-click the setup project in Solution Explorer and click **View**/**User Interface**.  Select the Start\Welcome dialog.  In the properties window there will be a **BitmapBanner** property where you can change the bitmap.  To change the alignment of the welcome text, you'd have to create a new/custom welcome dialog.

Comment: @Ganesh Up Vote/Mark as answer if this answer helped.